# Decrypt file using AES method in Android

Tags: php, android, encryption, aes, block-cipher

I have encrypted files using AES encryption in php with following code.

```
$ALGORITHM = 'AES-128-CBC';
$IV = '12dasdq3g5b2434b';
$password = '123';
openssl_encrypt($contenuto, $ALGORITHM, $password, 0, $IV);
```

Now I am trying to decrypt it in Android but always I face *InvalidKeyException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits* error. Here is android code:

```
String initializationVector = "12dasdq3g5b2434b";
String password = "123";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cryptFilepath);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
byte[] key = (password).getBytes("UTF-8");
MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
key = sha.digest(key);
key = Arrays.copyOf(key,16);
SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks, new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector.getBytes()));
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
int b;
byte[] d = new byte[16];
while((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
fos.write(d, 0, b);
}
fos.flush();
fos.close();
cis.close();
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are at least two bugs, in both codes different keys and modes are applied. The key used in the PHP code (`123`) is shorter (3 bytes) than specified (16 bytes because of `aes-128-cbc`), which is why it's automatically padded with `0` values, i.e. effectively the key `"123\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"` is used. Furthermore, the CBC mode is applied. In the Java code, a different key (first 16 bytes of the hash derived from the 3 bytes key using SHA1) is applied and another mode (ECB).

Comment: Another point is that `openssl_encrypt` returns the ciphertext currently Base64 encoded. Since the Java code reads the data from a file and doesn't perform a Base64 decoding, the data in the file must _already_ be Base64 decoded for it to work.

Comment: @Topaco thank you for your comments. Can you answer this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code posted in the question uses streams to read, decrypt and write the respective files. This makes it possible to process files that are larger than the available memory.

However, the originally posted code lacks the Base64 decoding, which is necessary because the ciphertext of the PHP code is Base64 encoded.

Base64 decoding can be comfortably achieved using the [`Base64InputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.html) class of Apache Commons Codec, which operates between `FileInputStream` and `CipherInputStream` and is therefore easy to integrate:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64InputStream;

...

public static void decrypt(String ciphertextFilepath, String decryptedFilePath) throws Exception {
    
    String password = "123";
    String initializationVector = "12dasdq3g5b2434b";

    byte[] key = new byte[16];
    byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.arraycopy(passwordBytes, 0, key, 0, passwordBytes.length);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ciphertextFilepath);
         Base64InputStream b64is = new Base64InputStream(fis);
         CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(b64is, cipher);
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(decryptedFilePath)) {
            
        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16]; // 16 bytes for testing, in practice use a suitable size (depending on your RAM size), e.g. 64 Mi
        while((read = cis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

The other fixed bugs / optimized points are (see also the other answers / comments):

- Use of the CBC mode analogous to the PHP code
- Use of the key from the PHP code
- Explicit specification of the used encoding

**Edit:** Consideration of an IV, see @Michael Fehr's comment.

Usually a new random IV is generated for each encryption. The IV is not secret and is commonly placed before the ciphertext and the result is Base64 encoded. The recipient can separate both parts, because the size of the IV is known (corresponds to the blocksize). This construct can also be used in combination with the `Base64InputStream` class, where the IV must be determined between the `Base64InputStream` instantiation and the `Cipher` instantiation/initialization:

```
...
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ciphertextFilepath);
     Base64InputStream b64is = new Base64InputStream(fis)){
        
    byte[] iv = b64is.readNBytes(16); // 16 bytes for AES
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            
    try (CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(b64is, cipher);
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(decryptedFilePath)) {
        ...
```

If during encryption IV and ciphertext are Base64 encoded *separately* and then concatenated, delimited by a separator (see @Michael Fehr's comment), the determination of the IV must be done between the `FileInputStream` and `Base64InputStream` instantiation (the separator must also be flushed).

Comment: just an academic question: If I would generate a random IV on PHP-side that comes together with the encrypted data how could this be implemented of PHP- and Java-side using the Apache Base64InputStream ? Usually I would Base64-encode the IV on PHP-side and write it along with the ciphertext ("::") and on java I split the resulting string, then Base64 decode and decrypt).

Answer (score 1):

The following full working examples show how to deal with the password issue and do Base64-decoding, the examples just work with string instead of files. Please keep in mind what @Topaco stated as openssl encodes the output in a Base64-encoding that needs to get converted to a byte-format before the file can get used with CipherInputStream for decryption!

A third point (not realy a bug) is that on Java/Android side you don't set a charset for the conversion from string to byte arrays - just add the StandardCharsets.UTF_8 and your're fine with that point.

**Beware that there is no proper exception handling !**

This is my sample PHP-code:

```
<?php
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63113746/decrypt-file-using-aes-method-in-android
$ALGORITHM = 'AES-128-CBC';
$IV = '12dasdq3g5b2434b';
$password = '123';
$plaintext = "my content to encrypt";
echo 'plaintext: ' . $plaintext . PHP_EOL;
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $ALGORITHM, $password, 0, $IV);
echo 'ciphertext: ' . $ciphertext . PHP_EOL;
$decryptedtext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $ALGORITHM, $password, 0, $IV);
echo 'decryptedtext: ' . $decryptedtext . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Output on PHP-side:

```
plaintext: my content to encrypt
ciphertext: DElx3eON2WX0MCj2GS8MnD+kn5NOu1i5IOTcrpKegG4=
decryptedtext: my content to encrypt
```

Sample Java-code:

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class DecryptInJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63113746/decrypt-file-using-aes-method-in-android");
        String password = "123";
        String initializationVector = "12dasdq3g5b2434b";
        String ciphertext = "DElx3eON2WX0MCj2GS8MnD+kn5NOu1i5IOTcrpKegG4="; // password 123 in openssl
        // openssl encodes the output in base64 encoding, so first we have to decode it
        byte[] ciphertextByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(ciphertext);
        // creating a key filled with 16 'x0'
        byte[] key = new byte[16]; // 16 bytes for aes cbc 128
        // copying the password to the key, leaving the x0 at the end
        System.arraycopy(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 0, key, 0, password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        // don't use just AES because that defaults to AES/ECB...
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] decryptedtext = cipher.doFinal(ciphertextByte);
        System.out.println("decryptedtext: " + new String(decryptedtext));
    }
}
```

Output on Java-side:

```
decryptedtext: my content to encrypt
```

Comment: I found tons of examples for string encryption and decryption. Can you edit your answer for a *file decryption* as the file is not *.txt* file, it is a media file.

Comment: Sorry but Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. As of @Topaco comments all points are cleared that prevents you from successful decrypting. The most important point why I do NOT write an example ist that the PHP-encryption has a Base64-output that cannot get decrypted in a single step but first needs to get decoded to a byte form (so you need a second, temporary) file. Using this decoded file it's jut a AES CBC file decryption and there are lot of examples when searching for it. The key and algorithm issues are solved with Topaco's and mine answer.

Comment: Posted the solution with the help of your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63114983/4291272), I wrote down the code which successfully decrypts the file.

Add following dependencies in your app level build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.7'
implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.13'
```

Java code:

```
public static void decrypt(String path, String outPath) throws Exception {
    String password = "123";
    String initializationVector = "12dasdq3g5b2434b";
    byte[] key = new byte[16]; // 16 bytes for aes cbc 128
    System.arraycopy(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 0, key, 0, password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

    byte[] input_file;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        input_file = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    } else {
        input_file = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(path));
    }

    byte[] decodedBytes;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(input_file);
    } else {
        decodedBytes = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(input_file);
    }

    byte[] decryptedtext = cipher.doFinal(decodedBytes);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outPath);
    fos.write(decryptedtext);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: A disadvantage of this implementation is that the file is loaded _completely_. As soon as the file is larger than the available memory, this won't work anymore. To avoid this problem, streams can be used so that the file is loaded successively, as in your first posted code (although the buffer there is actually unreasonably small). This code, however, did not Base64 decode the data before decryption. You can accomplish exactly this with the Apache Commons Codec's `Base64InputStream` class, which would operate _between_ your `FileInputStream` and `CipherInputStream`.

Comment: @Topaco can you put this comment as your answer with the change code and I will be happy to accept it. It will be really useful for others who are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Good answers but want to add my 2 cents regarding `Usually a new random IV is generated for each encryption`.  Change **Usually** to **NEED TO** or **MUST**.  I don't know of a reason NOT to use a new IV each time.    If you don't and happen to use the same key, the same data will encrypt to the same output each time.  This means that an attacker can tell if the decrypted values are the same just by comparing the encrypted values.  Encryption protects the original data from prying eyes, you still have to make sure they can't determine anything about the original data as well.  If you encrypt enough data, using the same Key and IV for each record, that can give an hacker a place to start an attacking your systems.